# Failed to execute goal org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.9.1.2184:sonar on project demo: You're not authorized to run analysis

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-scan, sonar-runner

Can anyone help me in getting solution for the below error.

Below are the version of the components to configure.

SonarQube Version 9.6.1

**Execution command**

```
stage('SonarQube') {
    container ('maven') {
        sh 'mvn -U verify sonar:sonar -Dsonar.host.url=http://serverId:9000  -Dsonar.login=mySonarqubeGlobalToken'
        sh 'mvn -U clean org.jacoco:jacoco-maven-plugin:prepare-agent package org.jacoco:jacoco-maven-plugin:report'
    }
}
```

**In My pom.xml**

```
<plugins>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.sonarsource.scanner.maven</groupId>
        <artifactId>sonar-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.9.1.2184</version>
    </plugin>
</plugins>
```

**In Console Window I am getting error**

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.9.1.2184:sonar (default-cli) on project demo: You're not authorized to run analysis. Please contact the project administrator. -> [Help 1]
```

Comment: It worked after I took User token from Sonarqube

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It worked after I took User token from Sonarqube –

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).